# How are object properties accessed internally?

Tags: c++, object, oop

In reference to this question:
[How are variable names stored in memory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612314/how-are-variable-names-stored-in-memory-in-c)

It is explained that in C, the compiler replaces variable names from code with actual memory addresses.

Let's take C++. I wonder how object properties are accessed in that context?

```
obj.prop
```

So obj gets replaced by the actual memory address. Does the compiler then replace prop with some sort of offset and add it to obj - ultimately replacing the whole expression with an absolute address?

Comment: On the platforms I work on, yes, that's basically what happens.  (There's additional hand-waving for inheritance or multiple inheritance.)  But that's an implementation detail, and not required by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple cases and hiding the language lawyer hat:

`obj.prop` is `*(&obj + &Obj::prop)`. The the second part is a member pointer, which is basically the offset of the property inside the object.

The compiler can replace that with an absolute address if it knows the address of the `obj` at compile time. Assuming it has an `obj` in memory at all. The `obj` could be kept completely in registers. Or only parts of the `obj` may exist at all. But generally `obj.prop` would turn into `pointer + offset`.

Note: for local variable the pointer could be the stack frame and the offset the offset of `obj` inside the stack frame + the offset of `prop` inside `Obj`.

Comment: Where are the offsets for the properties stored?

Comment: Nowhere really. They are known at compile time and used to generate code. But unless you create a member pointer those offsets are compiler internals and not objects.

Comment: OK, as you mentioned &Obj::prop I thought it was stored in the class object - as every instance has the same shape, it would work fine.