# Does javascript store variable names?

Tags: javascript, variables, memory

```
let num = 10;
console.log(num);
```

For example, if the value 10 stored at 0x123..

How does javascript recognize that the string "num" is associated with the address 0x123.. which contains the value 10?

I found an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612314/how-are-variable-names-stored-in-memory-in-c) about this process in C, basically the compiler discards the name and substitutes it with the address (the name of the variable is not preserved). Is it the same for javascript?

I am confused because javascript is different, it's just-in-time compiled. Every browser vendor probably implements their own version of this but I imagine that they share the same concepts.

Does this mean that it maintains a symbol table at all times to keep track of the relationship between the variable name and its address location?

I skimmed through the [ECMA specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) and read the MDN documentation and I am still lost.

Comment: are you talking about memory address?

Comment: Does this help?  https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-memory-management/

Comment: There's a symbol table at **some** point; how long a symbol might be in it would be  implementation (and execution context) dependent.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @asportnoy I think they're trying to understand JS implementations, specifically around reference lookups.

Comment: @asportnoy I am trying to gain a better understadning of what happens under the hood. Is the name of a variable stored anywhere in memory?

let myName = 'Penguin';

Is the literal string "myName" saved in memory?