# How does a program store variables?

Tags: memory, memory-management, programming-languages

When I declare a variable in, let's say C:

```
int x;
```

The compiler allocates memory, and assigns a memory address to that variable.

When I reference the variable again, the compiler generates some machine code that includes said memory address.

```
x = 5;
```

But how does the compiler "know" what the memory address belonging to `x` is? Wouldn't the compiler need to store the address itself somewhere and thus create a vicious cycle of consuming more and more memory to store the addresses? What am I missing?

Comment: `Wouldn't the compiler need to store the address itself somewhere` It knows where it puts variables, yes. `and thus create a vicious cycle of consuming more and more memory to store the addresses?` Where exactly do you see a cycle?

Comment: @tkausl I just noticed my question has been answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612314/how-are-variable-names-stored-in-memory-in-c?rq=2) post, but thank you.

Comment: compiled machine code does not contain any variables anymore, only memory addresses, so mapping between names and their addresses is used only during compilation and compiler uses memory during this process to store this table, but there is no cycle, just table